# Не могу разобраться с условием. LINQ

Tags: c#, xml, linq

Нужно найти все значение c, если значение value равно 5.

Какое условие поставить?

```
var res = dx.Descendants(XName.Get("value"));
```

```
<a>
    <value>5</value>
    <b>
      <c>12</c>
    </b>
    <b>
      <c>13</c>
    </b>
 </a>
 <a>
    <value>6</value>
    <b>
      <c>23</c>
    </b>
    <b>
      <c>24</c>
    </b>
</a>
```

Должно вывести: 12 13

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Один вариант:

```
var selectedValues =
            //Выбираем узлы «a»
            document.Descendants("a")
                //у которых значение value равно "5", предполагается что value есть всегда
                .Where(a => a.Element("value").Value == "5")
                //выбираем у каждого «a» всех дочерних «c»
                .Descendants("c")
                //и у каждого «c» выбираем значение
                .Select(c => c.Value);
```

Comment: Я бы вместо `.SelectMany(a => a.Descendants("c"))` использовал просто `.Descendants("c")`.

Comment: @VladD Спасибо большое! Не знал про [`Descendants(IEnumerable, XName)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345747(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Пожалуйста! Это удобная штука, хотя о ней мало знают.